# Include Static Files from templates Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

Project Structure:

```
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── static
│   └── admin
│       ├── css
│       ├── img
│       └── js
├── abc1
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── abc1
│   │       ├── homepage.html
│   │       ├── css
│   │       ├── img
│   │       ├── js
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
└── abc2
    ├── functions.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── views.py
    ├── wsgi.py
```

Settings.py File:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '../static'),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '../templates/abc1/img'),
)
```

homepage.html:

```
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}

    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/theme.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/magnific-popup.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Error Logs:

```
[08/Jan/2016 17:16:42] "GET /static/css/theme.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1643
[08/Jan/2016 17:16:42] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1655
[08/Jan/2016 17:16:42] "GET /static/css/magnific-popup.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1670

[08/Jan/2016 17:16:42] "GET /abc1/js/owl.carousel.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3579
[08/Jan/2016 17:16:42] "GET /abc1/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3570
[08/Jan/2016 17:16:42] "GET /abc1/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3594
```

I am trying to include the static css/js/img files in Django.
Can someone please point out my mistake ? 
(Couldn't figure out the exact issue/reason, So had to mention a lot of details)

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create one directory `static` in the main folder of project, wich contains `manage.py` and put all static in this folder. Create folders for `css`, `js`, `img`, and load it like you did before:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>
```

Use this settings:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

And you dont need this dots before path `../static`

Comment: static is already in the main folder of the project. How to add manage.py inside the static ? When I tried 'python manage.py collectstatic', Most of the css/js/Img files from abc1 were NOT included in the 'static' directory. So, I am not sure how to generate static for 'abc1' directory. Can you please elaborate a bit ?

Comment: you dont need `collect static` for make static work. I see you have directory named `admin`, so you need to load it like this `{% static 'admin/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}`  Also remove all static from here `os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '../templates/abc1/img'),` and put it in main static directory

Comment: no no. You dont understand me, you dont need to move `manage.py` in static folder. When I sayed "All static", I mean only your static, wich you add in project, like "bootstrap", also Django use other path, for native Django static, it is ok. So you have main folder, wich contains `dbsqlite`, `abs1` and `abs2` apps, and here you have `static` folder, this is dont load because you have other folder, in `static` name `admin`, so or delete this folder and create `js`, `css`, `img` in static folder, or add in path `{% static 'admin/css/bootstrap.min.css' %} ` like I sayed befor

Comment: Let me give it a try.

Comment: Okay. This seems to be working. But Now instead of 404, i m getting 304 for all. (All changes suggested done)